# Преобразование скалярных типов при сравнении JavaScript

Tags: javascript, типы-данных, сравнение

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему из трех алертов ниже исполняется только последний? Вроде как во всех трёх случаях идет мягкое сравнение на равенство к `true`

```js
if (true == "0") alert('Тру равно нулю!');

if ("0" == true) alert('Ноль равен тру');

if ("0") alert('Как бы тоже тру, или как?');
```

Comment: в сравнении "0" преобразуется в false, в последней же строке сравнения нет, непустая строка преобразуется в true. Тут [пишется](https://learn.javascript.ru/types-conversion#%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) - При сравнении с помощью «==» – численное преобразование, а в if – логическое, только и всего.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Стоит обратиться к [спецификации](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-equality-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation)
При вычислении равенства *EqualityExpression == RelationalExpression* получаются значения левой и правой части, и к ним применяется [*Abstract Equality Comparison*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-abstract-equality-comparison).

> Сравнение x == y, где x и y - значения, возвращает *true* or *false*. Такое сравнения производится следующим образом:
>   Если *Type(x)* тот же самый, что и *Type(y)*, тогда возвращается результат выполнения [Strict Equality Comparison](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-strict-equality-comparison) x === y.
>   Если *x* является **null** и *y* является **undefined**, вернуть *true*.
>   Если *x* является **undefined** и *y* является **null**, вернуть *true*.
>   Если *Type(x)* - это **Number** и *Type(y)* - это **String**,
>   вернуть результат выражения *x == ToNumber(y)*.
>   Если *Type(x)* - это **String** и *Type(y)* - это **Number**,
>   вернуть результат выражения *ToNumber(x) == y*.
>   Если *Type(x)* - это **Boolean**, вернуть результат выражения *ToNumber(x) == y*.
>   Если *Type(y)* - это **Boolean**, вернуть результат выражения *x == ToNumber(y)*.
>   Если *Type(x)* один из следующих: **String**, **Number**, или **Symbol** и *Type(y)* это **Object**, вернуть значение выражения *x == ToPrimitive(y)*.
>   Если *Type(x)* - это **Object** и *Type(y)* один из следующих: **String**, **Number**, или **Symbol**, вернуть значение выражения *ToPrimitive(x) == y*.
>   Вернуть *false*.

Рассмотрим первый пример:

```
true == "0"
```

Это выражении соответствует ветке

> Если *Type(x)* - это **Boolean**, вернуть результат выражения *ToNumber(x) == y*.

При приведении к числу получаем выражение: `1 == "0"`
попадаем в ветку

> Если *Type(x)* - это **Number** и *Type(y)* - это **String**,
>   вернуть результат выражения *x == ToNumber(y)*.

При приведении к числу получаем выражение: `1 == 0` и как результат: *false*.

Со вторым случаем происходит аналогичное.

Теперь рассмотрим третий случай.

Обратимся опять к [спецификации](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-if-statement-runtime-semantics-evaluation):

К выражению внутри скобок применяется функция [`ToBoolean`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-toboolean), которая в случае строки возвращает *false* если строка пустая(длина строки 0), и *true* - в противном случае.

Так как "0" - не пустая(длина строки 1), то условие считается выполненным.

Comment: Спасибо, отличное пояснение!

Answer (score 2):

1. Строка таки преобразуется в ноль, что трактуется как ложь.
2. То же самое, только наоборот аргументы.
3. Это не пустая строка, трактуется как `true`.

[Как оно происходит](https://learn.javascript.ru/types-conversion).

Comment: Ну вообще-то я оттуда и пришел. То, что Вы описали - это пересказ моего вопроса. Просто в том учебнике не указано, что при отсутствии оператора сравнения неявно вызывается `toBoolean` (ну или я не внимательно прочел). Но всеравно спасибо за внимание!

Comment: @tekken, вроде ответ есть как оно, впрочем, ответ Grundy куда полнее. Рекомендую не использовать `==` - это потенциальный выстрел в ногу, всегда используйте `===`; я ничего не потерял, зато обезопасил себя от загадочных лагов, т. к. преобразуются типы для сравнения весьма неоднозначно (это стоило бы поправить в новых спецификациях, конечно).