# Javascript, подбор параметров для функции

Tags: javascript

Всем доброго времени суток.
Дана функция:

```
function compare(a, b, c) {
   return a == b && b == c && a != c;
}
```

Нужно вернуть массив с набором таких параметров что бы при вызове эта функция вернула true.

```
compare(values[0], values[1], values[2]) === true;//OK
```

Пытался найти решение с помощью null, пока что без успехов

Answer (score 5):

Одним из решений может быть следующий массив

```
["0",0,""]
```

Как это работает?

При сравнении с помощью оператора `==` происходит приведение типов, если типы операндов отличаются. Подробнее в [соответствующем ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/518728/186999)

Рассмотрим отдельные сравнения:

1. `"0" == 0` - по спецификации, в этом случае строка "0" будет приведена к числу, и сравнение 0==0 даст `true`
2. `0==""` - [по той же спецификации](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-runtime-semantics-mv-s), пустая строка, при приведении к числу соответствует `0`, следовательно опять получается `0==0`
3. `"0" != ""` - типы операндов одинаковые, приведение не используется, строки действительно не равны. поэтому результат `true`.

```js
function compare(a, b, c) {
  return a == b && b == c && a != c;
}

var arr = ["0", 0, ""];
console.log(compare(arr[0], arr[1], arr[2]));
```