# зачем this в методе?

Tags: javascript

```js
var user = {
  name: 'Василий',

  sayHi: function() {
    alert( this.name );
  }
};

user.sayHi();
```

Чтобы функция получила доступ к свойству в объекта нужно прописать this а зачем если есть скрытое свойство [[scope]] ?

Comment: потому что это разные вещи

Comment: с чего ты взял, что есть скрытое свойство `[[scope]]`? Даже если предположить, что оно есть - оно потому и _скрытое_, что напрямую из кода к нему нет доступа

Comment: @Grundy при объявлении функции создается скрытое свойство [[scope]; написано ведь если функция не находит переменную в своем окружении она ищет в окруженнии в котом она создана]

Comment: @xes, _при объявлении функции создается скрытое свойство [[scope]];_ - с чего ты взял?

Comment: @Grundy https://learn.javascript.ru/object-conversion При создании функция получает скрытое свойство [[Scope]], которое ссылается на лексическое окружение, в котором она была создана.

Comment: Вот именно что на **лексическое окружение**, а не на поля объекта. `name` не относится к лексическому окружению

Comment: @andreymal тогда своими словами скажите что значит лексическое окружение

Comment: @xes зачем своими словами, если на том же сайте всё написано https://learn.javascript.ru/closures

Comment: @xes, там все устарело: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/ - в спецификации ничего нет про [[scope]]

Comment: @Grundy еще бы ты подвез знание английского :))

Comment: @xes, можешь поиском поискать - нет никакого упоминания

Comment: @Grundy  так и быть поверю ВАМ на слово :))

Comment: @andreymal чтобы лучше понять

Comment: @Grundy  а вот alert( [] == [] ); // false  можете прояснить ?

Comment: @xes, ты уже задавал такой вопрос, смотри [алгоритм сравнения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/518728/186999)

Comment: @Grundy а можно как-нибудь проще для тупых ?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88502/discussion-between-grundy-and-xes).