# Почему в данном примере ответ false?

Tags: javascript

```
let x=2;
let y=new Number(2);
console.log(x===y)//false
```

Почему???
Ведь и x, и y имеют тип number, и значения одинаковые?!

Comment: typeof y вернет вам Object

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Преобразование скалярных типов при сравнении JavaScript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/518721/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Вы путаете

```
number c Number
```

один из них строенный тип другой класс

```
typeof x // "number"
typeof y // "object"
```