# Нужно вывести массив с цифрами из каждой строки

Tags: javascript, массивы, строки

Есть строка. Нужно выделить и отобразить цифры. Указанный код работает. Представим массив из n строк. Нужно вывести массив с цифрами из каждой строки

```js
let data = {
  volume: ''
}
let arr = 'goodby! 78 .'
let number = ''
for (const word of arr) {
  if ('0123456789'.includes(word)) {
    number += word
  }
}
data.volume = number
console.log(data)
```

Comment: "Указанный код работает".  Вопрос в чём?

Comment: открыл инструменты разработчика в хроме - нет там никакого вопроса

Comment: ['d,gm56', 'sdgf23dsg', 'ds14gsd'] Нужно получить [ '56', '23', '14']

Answer (score 1):

```js
let arr1 = ['d,gm56', 'sdgf23dsg', 'ds14gsd'];
let arr2 = ['234d,gm56', 'sdgf23dsg', 'dsgsd', 'sdgg22'];

const test = arr => arr.join('').match(/\d+/g);

console.log(test(arr1));
console.log(test(arr2));
```

Comment: Отличный вариант

Answer (score 0):

Можно так попробовать решить. Хотя, возможно, коллеги смогут предложить решения без двойного обхода

```js
let test = ['d,gm56', 'sdgf23dsg', 'ds14gsd', 'testword', '12312sdfsdf99'];

let arr = []

function getNumbers(testArray) {
  testArray.forEach(function(elem) {
    let matches = elem.match(/\d+/g);
    if (matches) {
      matches.forEach(function(match) {
        arr.push(parseInt(match));
      });
    }
  });
  return arr;
}

console.log(getNumbers(test));
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать вот так:

```js
const arr = ['d,gm56', 'sdgf23dsg', 'ds14gsd']

function onlyNumbers(data) {
  let resultArr = []

  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    const str = data[i]
    const number = str.replace(/\D/g, '')

    if(number) {
      resultArr.push(number)
    }
  }

  return resultArr
}

const result = onlyNumbers(arr)

console.log(result)
```

#### Объяснение

В строке которую вы получаем я убираю всё что не является числом с помощью метода `replace`. В методе написано регулярное выражение `\D` (оно означает *НЕ число*), оно равноценно такой записи: `[^\d]`, а эта запись в свою очередь равноценна этой: `[^0-9]`. Я добавил флаг `g` в конце регулярного выражения чтобы оно применялось на всю строку, а не только на первый символ. Дальше идёт проверка `number`, проверяется являться ли она falsy, чуть подробнее можно прочитать [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/518721/) или же [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Glossary/Falsy), сейчас только упомяну, что если переменная `number` пустая (то-есть длина строки равна нулю), то тогда она считается falsy и проверку не проходит, соответственно не попадает в массив с результатами. Если же `number` валидно (то-есть является [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Glossary/Truthy)), то тогда оно попадает в массив с результатами.